# Decimal to Char Expression Informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

Expression transformation:

Source: DECIMAL(38,15)

Example: 11.500000000000000

Target: Flat File

When I do not make any modifications to the source it gives me 11.499999999999999 (rounds it), I do not want the rounding, I just want 11.500000000000000. I made an attempt to use TO_CHAR in the expression transformation and got 11.5. The problem is the zeroes are taken away. I tried to do TO_CHAR with a RPAD/INSTR without any luck.

Can someone please give me some assistance!

Comment: Try enabling high precision in session properties

Comment: Tried that, no luck. Same result.

Comment: Well, then you have to separate the integer and decimal part. Then RPAD 15 zeros to the decimal part and concat them back.

Comment: Use substr with instr for separating the two parts. You would better use a few variable ports.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the below

SELECT TO_CHAR(11.500000000000000, 99.999999999999999) FROM DUAL;

I tried it on SQL and its working fine. Let me know if it is working fine in your case.

Thanks
Raj